# Adding objects to existing entity groups (Java App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity

I have two objects, lets call them "User" and "Skill". When a person 
signs up to my site they are saved as a "User". A user may have 
multiple skills, these are stored as a list within the User object, 
e.g.

```
@Persistent @Element(dependent = "true") 
private List<Skill> skills;
```

Now what I need to determine is how to add a Skill object to the User 
entity group when I create it, as I need to modify both objects within 
a single transaction. 
When I create Skill objects do I have to supply the User key to the 
new Skill object somehow? 
I'd appreciate any help I can get with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, except creating the two objects in the same transaction, and make the user persistent. Read http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Relationships_Entity_Groups_and_Transactions

Comment: The issue is I cant create the User and Skill objects at the same time. The User object is created when they sign up and Skill objects are created and added to the "skills" list at a later date.

Comment: It's not a problem. Just add the new skill to the list, and it will be made persistent automatically.

Comment: It is a problem because if I simply add a skill to the list, when it comes to modifying and persisting a User and a Skill object within the same transaction I get this error:

can't operate on multiple entity groups in a single transaction.

Comment: Do you add a new, non-persistent skill to a persistent User. If yes, then it should work, as explained in the doc I linked to. If you make a skill persistent in a transaction, and then add this skill into a User in another one, then it won't work. Show us the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I create a new Skill object, fetch the User object from the datastore, and then add the Skill onject to the User i.e.

`userObj.skillList.add(skillObj)`

And then I persist the User i.e.

`pm.makePersistent(userObj)`

So I do not persist the skillObj before adding it to the userObj skill list.

Answer (score 0):

(for JDO)
If it's an [owned relationship](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships) your skill should contain a member of type user lets say

```
@Persistent
private User owner;
```

and User contains

```
@Persistent(mappedBy="owner")
private List<Skill> skills;
```

so when you create a new Skill pass the owning user in the constructor *new Skill(someUser)* and assign in to the owner member. Once you'll persist this entity, the mapping is done and now accessing the user's **skills** list will produce all skills "owner" is this user.

There are some issues with JDO relationship implementation on app engine as JDO is more relational DB oriented. You can find more about it in the reference link and plain ol' google.